# I want search for a string and to pull all the lines between two patterns

Tags: shell, awk, sed, perl, aix

I want search for a string and  to pull all the lines between two patterns(including the pattern).

```
START#1

Name S

101

Frankfurt_1_1

19

A+

Street


END


START#2

Name B

104

Berlin

20

A+

Street


END



START#100

Name C

107

Berlin

21

A+

Street

END



START#24

Name D

110

Frankfurt_1_1

21

A+



END
```

If I `grep` Frankfurt

Then it has to display all the lines between START and END(including START AND END) like :

```
START#1

Name S

101

Frankfurt_1_1

19

A+

Street


END


START#24

Name D

110

Frankfurt_1_1

21

A+

Street


END
```

Command which I used :

```
cat file | awk '/START/,/END/' | grep -p Frankfurt
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Blank lines does present in file or not required ?

Comment: @arzyfex blank lines are required .

Comment: how many blank lines present between each line ? is it uniform or randomly created ?

Comment: @arzyfex the blank lines count may vary. It's randomly created

Answer (score 1):

Not sure awk is the correct tool for that job since your search is over multiple lines based.
I would think it's a job for perl. Going through your file you can use (similar to your awk statement):

```
if (/^START/ .. /^END/){}
```

in there you store your lines in an array, that you're going to print if say Frankfurt is met (use a boolean here):

```
push @lines, $_;
if (/Frankfurt/)
        $toPrint = 1;
```

and in all cases when you're out of your pattern you, print the array if your boolean is true, don't print otherwise, empty you're array.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely we can use `awk`, try this one

```
awk -v RS="END" '$0~/Frankfurt/{print $0 RS}' file
```

Comment: it's not working . Nothing is displayed

Comment: @user4432340 : How is it possible.. I have tried this on my box, it displays what you needed. make sure you enter correct filename.

Comment: START#

Name S

101

Frankfurt_1_1

19

A+

Street


END
ND



START#

Name D

110

Frankfurt_1_1

21

A+         It's giving this output note: i have replaced START with START# and Frankfurt with Frankfurt_1_1

Comment: @user4432340 please update this in question. I don't understand what you are trying to show. There is update button on below of your question. Please update it.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: @user4432340: No matter what you change in START or Frankfurt, it is always searching for END string in it. Use the same command. make sure you enter proper command with correct filename. I am getting same output which you required.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38726/discussion-between-arzyfex-and-user4432340).